# Is a five-block horizontal jump in minecraft legitimately real?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I saw videos of people doing five-block horizontal jumps, but I can’t do it in Minecraft. How?

Comment: Can you link to your sources? Are you sure they weren't using mods?

Comment: Apparently it's possible without mods but requires some very strange and specific precision and circumstances that's difficult for many players to pull off. Though as far as we know, five blocks are the limit for this.

Comment: 5 block jump vertically, or horizontally?

Comment: Speed boost, jump boost (be it from potions or beacons), or just glide the gap on elytra. Combining the three you can cover a 10 block gap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is with certain potions, with this jump the least you will need is Speed 1, but any higher and the jump gets a little easy although, it takes time to adjust to the new speed. If you're making a server please consider using the /effect command by giving yourself a command block by using:

```
/give @s command_block 1
```